# Numbers in a file

Tags: java

I'm just a beginner and got the following task:

*Write first 100 positive and 100 negative integers to the file, listing them separated by a space.
Then read this file and put the read numbers into 2 files: positive_numbers and negative_numbers.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File numbers = new File("C:\\numbers.txt");
        File positivNumbers = new File("C:\\positivnumbers.txt");
        File negativNumbers = new File("C:\\negativnumbers.txt");


        try (
                BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(numbers));
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(numbers));
                BufferedWriter brnegativ = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(negativNumbers));
                BufferedWriter brpositiv = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(positivNumbers));) {

            if (numbers.exists()) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    wr.write(String.valueOf((i) + " "));
                }
                for (int a = -1; a >= -100; a--) {
                    wr.write(((a) + " "));
                }

                String line = rd.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    brpositiv.write(line);
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I could write numbers as a String to file "numbers". But I cannot read and write them in "positiv"   output file.The file is empty. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Don't forgot to `.close()` all `Buffered...` after you are done with them.

Comment: My first thought here is that I'd want to flush and close the BufferedWriter for numbers.txt before I started trying to read from it, just to make sure it was complete, and I wouldn't hit a file lock problem.  Try putting the code that writes to `wr` in a separate `try` block.

Answer (score 3):

After the writing you have to close `wr` so all data in memory gets flushed to the file. AFTER the close you can reopen it for read. So in your code you open `rd` too soon.

```
   try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(numbers));) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            wr.write(String.valueOf((i) + " "));
        }
        for (int a = -1; a >= -100; a--) {
            wr.write(((a) + " "));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // file is closed by try-with-resources ...

    // ... so now we can open it for read:
    try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(numbers));
         BufferedWriter brnegativ = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(negativNumbers));
         BufferedWriter brpositiv = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(positivNumbers));) {
            String line = rd.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                brpositiv.write(line);
               // TODO : split logic
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```